# What is the difference between "with" and "new" for context parameters in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-3

Is there a difference if I define a `given` value for a context parameter using the keyword `with` or using `new`?

for example is there a difference between `human` and `cat` `given`s?

```
 trait Talker:
  def talk:String

given human:Talker with
  def talk:String = "I am human"

given cat:Talker = new:
  def talk:String = "I am cat, meow"

def run(using t:Talker):Unit =
  println(t.talk)
```

Comment: `with` is more idiomatic but no difference

Comment: The `=` syntax is intended for creating an alias to an already existing value; I would say that using `new` like that would raise a couple of eye browns during code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a clear difference on compiled class level when using `new` vs `with`.

When using `with`, there is a dedicated class created, we can see it in the de-compiled code. Here is how it looks in Java

```java
public final class Talker$package {
   public static final class human$ implements Talker, Serializable {
      public static final Talker$package.human$ MODULE$ = new Talker$package.human$();

      private Object writeReplace() {
         return new ModuleSerializationProxy(Talker$package.human$.class);
      }

      public String talk() {
         return "I am human";
      }
   }
}
```

It has a dedicated class `human$` that extends `Talker`.

And on the other hand when using `new` for `cat`, we have an anonymous class.

```java
public final class Talker$package {
   public static Talker cat() {
      return Talker$package$.MODULE$.cat();
   }
}
```

where `MODULE$.cat()` eventually points to following

```java
Talker var5 = new Talker() {
    public String talk() {
       return "I am cat, meow";
    }
};
```

Comment: you say "When using new, there is a dedicated class created," and then you refer to `human`, but I am using `with` with human and not `new`, so how come a dedicated class was created for it?

Comment: @HHH sorry, i got them swapped  in my answer. `new` will be anonymous, `with` will be a dedicated class